# Trig: Using Inverse Functions With Sum-Difference Formula

Tags: trigonometry

If we are solving a problem like:

> $$\sin\left[\arccos\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right) +\arctan\left(-\sqrt{3}\right)\right]$$

We would have to use the sum-difference formula:

> $\sin(a+b)$ or $\sin(a-b)$

My question is: how would we determine if one of the terms, $a$ or $b$, is negative?

In attempting to solve the example above, I drew out two triangles and obtained:

$$\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$$

but I am worried that one of them (or both) may have had to be negative.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values

Answer (score 3):

You'd better draw a trigonometric circle. You just need to know 
$\;\arccos x\in [0,\pi]$ (on this interval, the sine is nonnegative) and $\arctan x\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ (on this interval the cosine is  positive, and  sine & tangent have the same sign).

*Example:* 
$\;\text{set}\;\theta=\arccos(-\frac12)=\frac{2\pi}3$. Then $\sin \theta=\frac{\sqrt3}2$, and naturally $\cos\theta=-\frac12$. Similarly, from $\;\tan\varphi=-\sqrt3$, deduce $\sin\varphi$ and $\cos\varphi$, using the standard identities
$$\sin^2\varphi=\frac{\tan^2\varphi}{1+\tan^2\varphi},\qquad\cos^2\varphi=\frac1{1+\tan^2\varphi}.$$

Comment: Not sure I follow... Given arccos(-1/2) for example, does that mean it has to be negative sqrt(3)/2? I am aware of the intervals, I am not sure how to make use of them given the example I used above.

Comment: @Matt: I've added some details.